# How to detect or listen ssh activity that connect to docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

is there any method to auto detect or listen the activity connect to docker container via ssh?

OS: linux

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more informations about what exactly are you trying to achieve. Do you have docker container with SSH service and you want to get eg. some log of SSH activity or something else?

Comment: Yes, i have docker container running SSH service. i need to be notified when someone connect into containers via SSH. Is there any linux commands or scripts that can get the connection information? Thanks for the help.